# Problem with \ContinuedFloat subfigs

Tags: tables, subfloats, ref

I am trying to have multiple tabulars as subfloats using the subfig package and the table environment. Adding another table environment and binding them with \ContinuedFloat and stopping the table-counter from rising (using \addtocounter{table}{0} ) I am getting questionsmarks when using \ref to refer to either subref of any subfloat or label of the second table environment, which table counter didn't rise.

To add up another error, I am getting question marks next to the subfloat captions, when there are more than 1 subfloat in a table environment

```
\documentclass[
fontsize=12pt,        
BCOR=1cm,                           
DIV=12,                              
parskip=half,          
numbers=noendperiod
]{scrartcl}

%general stuff
\usepackage[english,ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage{tgheros}

%table-edits
\usepackage{threeparttable}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{ltxtable}   
\usepackage{tabularx}
\newcolumntype{L}[1]{>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}p{#1}}
\newcolumntype{C}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}X}
\newcolumntype{M}[1]{>{\centering}m{#1}}    

%others
\usepackage{subfig}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{multirow, multicol}
\usepackage{lscape}
\usepackage{todonotes}

\begin{document}

    \begin{landscape}

        \begin{table}[h] 
            \centering
            \caption{overall caption}
            \label{tab:overalllabel}
            %1  
            \subfloat[subtabular-1]{
                \begin{tabular}{|M{3cm}|M{3cm}|}
                \hline
                                    & bla \tabularnewline
                    bla             & bla \tabularnewline

                \hline
                \end{tabular}   }
                \subref{tab:tabular1}

            \subfloat[subtabular-2]{
                \begin{tabular}{|M{3cm}|M{3cm}|}
                    \hline
                    & bla \tabularnewline
                    bla             & bla \tabularnewline

                    \hline
            \end{tabular}   }
            \subref{tab:tabular2}
            \end{table}

        \begin{table}[h] 
            \centering
            \caption*{overall caption-continued}
            \label{tab:overalllabel_1}
            \ContinuedFloat
            \addtocounter{table}{0}
            %1  
            \subfloat[subtabular33]{
                \begin{tabular}{|M{3cm}|M{3cm}|}
                    \hline
                                    & bla \tabularnewline
                    bla             & bla \tabularnewline
                    \hline
                \end{tabular}   }
            \subref{tab:tabular3}
        \end{table}

    \end{landscape}

    \ref{tab:overalllabel}
    \ref{tab:overalllabel_1}
    \ref{tab:tabular1}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably this is what you wanted to achieve:

```
\documentclass[
fontsize=12pt,        
BCOR=1cm,                           
DIV=12,                              
parskip=half,          
numbers=noendperiod
]{scrartcl}

%general stuff
\usepackage[english,ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage{tgheros}

%table-edits
\usepackage{threeparttable}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{ltxtable}   
\usepackage{tabularx}
\newcolumntype{L}[1]{>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}p{#1}}
\newcolumntype{C}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}X}
\newcolumntype{M}[1]{>{\centering}m{#1}}    

%others
\usepackage{subfig}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{multirow, multicol}
\usepackage{lscape}
\usepackage{todonotes}

\begin{document}

   % \begin{landscape}

        \begin{table}[h] 
            \centering
            \caption{overall caption}
            \label{tab:overalllabel}
            %1  
            \subfloat[subtabular-1]{
                \begin{tabular}{|M{3cm}|M{3cm}|}
                \hline
                                    & bla \tabularnewline
                    bla             & bla \tabularnewline

                \hline
                \end{tabular} \label{tab:tabular1}}


            \subfloat[subtabular-2]{
                \begin{tabular}{|M{3cm}|M{3cm}|}
                    \hline
                    & bla \tabularnewline
                    bla             & bla \tabularnewline

                    \hline
            \end{tabular}\label{tab:tabular2}}
            \end{table}

        \begin{table}[h]
        \ContinuedFloat 
            \centering
            \caption{overall caption-continued}
            \label{tab:overalllabel_1}
            \subfloat[subtabular33]{
                \begin{tabular}{|M{3cm}|M{3cm}|}
                    \hline
                                    & bla \tabularnewline
                    bla             & bla \tabularnewline
                    \hline
                \end{tabular}\label{tab:tabular3}} 
        \end{table}

%    \end{landscape}

    \ref{tab:overalllabel}
    \ref{tab:overalllabel_1}
    \subref{tab:tabular1}

\end{document}
```

Comment: That easy? All it took was replacing \subref with \label ?!
Thanks alot!

Comment: @lm4X: I also moved the `\continuedFloat` command before the `\caption` in the second `table` environment. You can also remove the `\addtocounter{table}{0}` command.